# reset count if cell in a range is blank in googlesheets

Tags: google-sheets

i am trying to get my spreadsheet to count the number of consecutive shifts undertaken by a member of staff, but when the reference cell range is blank I want the count to reset to zero.

Using the countif formula I can get it to total the shifts, but after a blank it does not reset to zero and after the blanks the count continues minus the number of blanks.

The formula references row 6 and is searching for "NSC" and "SC".

I have shared a link to a copy of the spreadsheet, can you assist?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kqVaJqKaFnC51lWxjrNq1AeIisf_7uu2htoVf9rm0F8/edit?usp=sharing

Regards

Brian

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this with a formula. If you are open to using script, this will do it:

```
function countText() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet()
  var lc=s.getLastColumn()
  var rng=s.getRange(6, 5, 1, lc).getValues()//starting at E6
  var count=0 //set count to 0
  for (var i=0;i<rng[0].length;i=i+3){//skip to the next col that could contain 'SC' or 'NSC'
     if(rng[0][i]=="SC" || rng[0][i]=="NSC"){
      count=count+1
      s.getRange(5, i+6, 1, 1).setValue(count)//set the count value in row 5
  }
      else if(rng[0][i]==""){
      s.getRange(5, i+6, 1, 1).setValue("") //set row 5 to blank
      count=0 //reset the count to 0
      }
  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

AV5:

```
=(COUNTIF(AU6,"NSC")+COUNTIF(AU6,"SC")+AS5)*NOT(ISBLANK(AU6))
```

Copy and paste in corresponding cells.